# How to enable ssh for a user with root permissions?

Tags: ssh, password, root

I have added a user **test** with root permissions. In my `sshd_config` file I have kept **permitrootlogin** as **No**, to block ssh for root. I am not able to do ssh for root which works fine, but the issue is i am not able to login **test** user also  via ssh.

How can I fix this issue?

`/etc/passwd` extracts:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh

test:x:0:0::/home/test:/usr/sbin/myshell
```

Comment: Is there a password hash in `/etc/shadow` for user `test`? Also, what error message do you get?

Comment: yes the shadow file hashes are different for root and test .I am not able login to test user via ssh.the error shows related to authentication failures

Comment: Just set `PermitRootLogin` to `without-password` instead of `no` and use public key auth to login as root. Or just set a strong password. What are you supposed to achive by creating a `test` alias for `root`?

Comment: I'm not even sure how well supported multiple passwd entries with the same uid are. The `userdel(1)` from the shadow package will refuse the delete your `test` user. Having `getpwuid(pw->pw_uid)` return a different entry than `pw` is certainly very confusing.

Comment: Thank u moosy for suggestions will try with that without-password option.For test user we wanted to use some functionality which can done by root ,but unfortunately sudo ,su are absent in our linux customer build .so we have gone for setting the options for test as root with uid 0

Comment: Your "test" account is root.  root is any user with `uid=0`, no matter what the login name is.   There can be more than one root login name on a system, but there is only one root.

Comment: btw, if your designers think that not installing & configuring `su` or `sudo` etc is more secure than having a second root login with a different name and shell, then they need to do an introductory unix security course.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this issue by creating a normal user for login, and then using a local escalation tool (`su`, `sudo`, `doas`, `pkexec`...) to gain root privilege.

OpenSSH (like many other tools) does not restrict root based on the string "root", but rather on the privileged UID zero.  Since you have set the UID of your new user to zero, it will fail to login in exactly those situations where root cannot login.

For one example, from `userauth_finish()` in [`auth2.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/auth2.c?rev=1.156&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) in the OpenSSH source:

```
    /* Special handling for root */
    if (authenticated && authctxt->pw->pw_uid == 0 &&
        !auth_root_allowed(ssh, method))
            authenticated = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your info,but unfortanely in our linux board sudo support is not there.i have edited the sshd_config to support test user by  adding the following lines   PermitRootLogin                 "yes" DenyUsers   "root".can we do like this?It is working for me?